# Do women and men get paid equally in Canada?

Tags: government, canada

I am wondering whether the Canadian government has rules or policies for paying people equally regardless of the gender. If not, what is the reason for the difference in earnings?

Comment: There is definitely a gap but I' not sure what the federal government is doing about it. Regarding your question, you are asking about the federal or provincial governments ?

Comment: @Vincent I am interested in both. but more towards provincial.

Comment: Are you looking for one in particular ? You should add these details in the question.

Comment: The gender pay gap (which exists practically everywhere) is not always as much a result of workplace sexism as it seems to be at first glance. An important factor is that in many cultures, women are statistically more likely to choose professions with lower average pay. *Why* they do is another issue, but unlikely to be one which can be fought with laws and regulations.

Comment: Consider gender pay gap for the followings: if 90 of 100 programmers are male while 90 out of 100 in cleaning jobs are done by female then the average income gap between these 200 people will be huge. Even if programmers AND cleaning staff are paid equally each. Furthermore if a woman goes to give birth three times, they will miss out 3-5 years of carieer life which is perfectly acceptable, but if you look for experienced person, the amount of experience matters, not the gender.

Answer (score 3):

Several Canadian provinces/territories have [Pay Equity Acts](http://www.payequity.gov.on.ca/en/about/pubs/genderwage/pe_survey.php).

I don't understand all the ins-and-outs of Canadian law, but in general it looks like these acts don't require that pay between individual men and women be equal.  Instead, job roles can be categorized as "male dominated" or "female dominated".  Female dominated job roles will have their pay adjusted to be similar to male dominated roles.